# Plot Arg[z] in three dimensions

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, complex

I would like to plot the function `Arg[z]` for a complex number $z$ in three-dimensions: I would like to obtain it as a surface over the complex plane, as in the "3D plot" section of [this page](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arg%28z%29%20plot):

[image]

But I would also like to be able to modify the range and the colors. The function only assumes real values between $-\pi$ and $\pi$.

I found (and tried) `Complex3DPlot`, but it does not provide what I'm looking for, because it plots the magnitude of `Arg[z]`.

Comment: Is this what you want? ``Plot3D[Arg[x + I y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]``

Comment: @Domen Yes, exactly! Thank you. I had tried something similar and it didn't work, maybe I used a wrong syntax. If you would like to make an answer, it's welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Plot3D` with $z = x + iy$.

```
Plot3D[Arg[x + I y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]